# <p:row> under <p:outputPanel> isn't working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have faced a problem about rendering `<p:outputPanel>` inside which I have placed `<p:row>`.

How I can solve this problem??

Any pointer will be very helpful to me. Thanks.

### Edit

```
<p:panelGrid>

---

  <p:outputPanel rendered="#{condition}">
    <p:row>
    <p:row>
  </p:outputPanel>
</p:panelGrid>
```

In this case if I set the value of the rendered condition to true, then also the row is not getting displayed.

Comment: And what is your problems?!

Comment: `<p:outputPanel>` is not working inside this I have placed `<p:row>`. This is my prob.. I want to render `<p:row>` by rendering `<p:outputPanel>` but this is not working.

Comment: `<p:outputPanel>` has no relation to `<p:row>`. `<p:row>` is used inside `<p:dataTable>` and `<p:outputPanel>` is just a container.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn I have added a small code snippet to clarify my query.

Comment: What is your intention? Do you need rows in a table? `<p:outputPanel>` does not support rows! It is not table. It is just a simple container that can hold other components. It's like `<div/>` tag. If you need a table with multiple rows, use `<p:dataTabe>` See: [DataTable](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html), [OutputPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/outputPanel.jsf) and [PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf). Also read the [documentatoin](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Comment: @MD.Unicorn  : In `<p:panelGrid>` I have placed many `<p:row>` , only inside one I want to take a `<p:dataTable>` . I want to render the containing `<p:row>` of `<p:dataTable>`..

Comment: @MD.Unicorn thanks for you suggestion. As `<p:outputPanel/>` doesn't support row inside that is why I think it is not rendering. Can conditionally render the `<p:row/>`? I have tried to add the same condition on `<p:row/>` without the `<p:outputPanel/>` and tried to `update` that row through ajax, but that is not working, I guess the row primarily not present in the DOM, that is why is not getting visible after ajax update. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please answer a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<p:row>` with panelGrid or DataTable. SomeThing like this...

```
<p:panelGrid rendered="#{condition}">
   <p:row>
       <p:column>AAA</p:column>
   </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```